# Parse Json file with Jquery return nothing

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I am trying to parse json file in my PhoneGap application. After searching on Stackoverflow I found this code.

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://www.shobingg.com/cms/sites/php/message.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xunG/)

You can see the original post here

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You just asked this. The issue is you are not allowed to do this cross origin. Adding the callback does not work if the site does not support jsonp. Did you add the site to phonegap's whitelist as I suggested in the other question?

Comment: in the whitlist i am useing the * and still not working ... but it is not working on the JSFiddle also so the problem not from the phonegap

Answer (score 1):

Ok.This is not the only way you can parse the json in your application.This is actually `JSONP-Json With Padding` and You are talking about `JSON.`In JSONP we require a callback function when we request for `JSON` data from the server.Instead of using `JSONP` use `JSON`.Just call the `JSON` file ,get the response and parse it with using `Ajax` Request.

e.g.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'Your URL,
        success: function(response) 
               {
                  var ss = JSON.parse(response);
                      console.log(ss);
                }
            });
```

This code is worked for me when i was developing my PhoneGap application.I required JSON data in my application and i got data through this code.Hope this will help you.